# Rails : assigns hash in ActionController::TestCase and ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ruby On Rails Tutorials, [Listing 10.31 Listing 10.31: Adding account activation to the user signup test.](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/account_activation_password_reset#code-account_activation_edit_action)

I get nil instead of a valid user on this line:
      user = assigns(:user)

The codes are here:

## ./test/integration/users_signup_test.rb

```
....
class UsersSignupTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "valid signup information" do    
    assert_difference 'User.count', 1 do
    post_via_redirect users_path, user: { name:  "testA",
                                        email: "testA@valid.com",
                                        password:               "foobar",
                                        password_confirmation:  "foobar" }
    end
    assert_equal 1, ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size
    debugger
    user = assigns(:user) 
    ....
```

## ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)   
  if @user.save
    UserMailer.account_activation(@user).deliver_now
    flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
    redirect_to root_url  
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

The dubug info shows there is no *:user* in the assigns hash:

```
Run options: --seed 10699

# Running:

..............
[35, 44] in /home/artreal/Codes/hello_world/test/integration/users_signup_test.rb
   35: 
   36:     assert_equal 1, ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size
   37: 
   38:     debugger
   39: 
   => 40:     user = assigns(:user)   #assigns (a hash) lets us access instance variables in controllers 
   41: 
   42:     assert_not user.activated?
   43:     # Try to log in before activation.
   44:     log_in_as(user)
(byebug) p assigns
{"marked_for_same_origin_verification"=>true}
{"marked_for_same_origin_verification"=>true}
(byebug)
```

And here is the error:

```
1) Error:
UsersSignupTest#test_valid_signup_information:
NoMethodError: undefined method `activated?' for nil:NilClass
test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:42:in `block in <class:UsersSignupTest>'
```

The routes seems to be correct:

```
...
users    GET    /users(.:format)                        users#index
         POST   /users(.:format)                        users#create
new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                    users#new
...
```

The API document of *ActionController::TestCase* (can't post a link) has a section on the assign hash. 
But the API doc of *ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest* (can't post a link) does not say anything on the same hash.

What did I miss on using assign in integration test?

Comment: You better to verify your source code with tutorial once again. Or post `create` action at least.

Comment: Hi Dimakura, updated the question with the full `create` action. I tried a debug in the `create` action, and confirmed that a valid user can be created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

In the integration test, I used the line:

```
post_via_redirect users_path, user: { name:  "testA",
                                    email: "testA@valid.com",
                                    password:               "foobar",
                                    password_confirmation:  "foobar" }
```

Instead, the tutorial is using a simple `post` function.

```
post   users_path, user: { name:  "testA",
                             email: "testA@valid.com",
                             password:               "foobar",
                             password_confirmation:  "foobar" }
```

Is it because the redirect part removed values in the `assign` hash?